# Is it possible to make python requests act like a web browser by executing a websites java script?

Tags: javascript, python, http, web-scraping, python-requests

When you use python requests you have to do everything manually, for example all the headers must be set manually which makes life pretty hard. However with a web browser everything is done automatically because of java script. For example, when you click a button on a website some java script is executed and the script instructs the web browser to send a request and it sets all the headers for you. But, when you use python requests there is no java script so you have to make the program do everything yourself so you have to look at the request, copy it into your program and hope it works. So my question is, is there a way to use the python requests module and execute the websites java script so that life is made easier for you. I hope my question was clear. Thanks.

Comment: no ... if you want to actually execute js you will need something like selenium...  I dont really understand the problem you are trying to solve ... usually you would just make a dictionary of headers and reuse it as needed ... requiring js for headers, seems like a very big hammer

Comment: @Joran How come a web browser can execute js but python cant

Comment: @JoranBeasley The reason I want to use js is for things like CSRFTokens and custom headers and just to make the thing a whole lot faster.

Comment: Because a web browser is running a JS engine, which knows how to interpret and run JS code. Python is just... well, python.

Comment: What if I found some way theoretically to execute JS from python then would that make python requests faster @zcoop98

Comment: Browsers don't use Javascript to follow a link, they just create the HTTP request with internal code, typically written in C++. It doesn't matter though what it is written in as populating the headers is quick and simple. Python does it fine. Adding Javascript to do it would only make it slower. If you only need to do requests to known URLs, it's fine to use use requests and e.g. make a function to populate headers the way you want. It's fast. If you need to run Javascript, use a browser using a lib like Selenium like suggested before.

Comment: @antont so how does a web browser create a custom header like a request id or a csrf token.

Comment: They don't, they are created on the server: "A CSRF token is a unique, secret, unpredictable value that is generated by the server-side application" https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens

Comment: @antont what about request ids are they the same

Comment: you can typically get csrf from the cookies (which iirc you can access from requests)... I think you can also use some sort of sessions concept with `session = requests.session(); result1= session.post(login_uri,data);result2=session.get(second_uri)`

Comment: @user13769517 i am relatively sure you can get all the items you need without javascript ... if you really need javascript use a library like selenium, not requests, it can certainly make it easier if you dont quite understand what your doing  (and in rare cases may even be required depending on how the site is served)